# How to make AR program become more complex

Tags: java, c#, android, augmented-reality

Hi guys I just make a simple app using AR with unity and vuforia.
I have problem that I couldn't solve, so I want my app become more complex.
In this photo I want the apps not just only contain 1 char and 1 marker I want it has more than 2 char and more marker so I can switch from char 1 to char 2 or another char in the bottom of the apps.
thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add more image target and assign characters to them the same way you did with the first image target. If you want all your character to appear at the same time go to the editor of ARCamera, there is a given choice of how many simulation at a time. set it to the number you want.

Was this your question? it not, please provide more explanation.